# MySQL: join tables in such a way, so that the rows with the same foreign key would combine into one

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have 2 tables:
One contains all of the products, the other one contains all of the categories for the products.
For one category there may be more than one input field for the category. Few examples:

```
+-------------+--------+
| SKU         | WV2323 |
| Name        | DVD    |
| Price       | 2.00   |
| >(category) | dvd    |
| memory      | 700MB  |
+-------------+--------+

+-------------+-----------+
| SKU         | bla3434   |
| Name        | Chair     |
| Price       | 50.00     |
| >(category) | furniture |
| height      | 70cm      |
| width       | 50cm      |
| length      | 100cm     |
+-------------+-----------+
```

All the values for the categories are in the categories table, connected to product via product_id. So if there are 3 fields for the product category, they are contained as 3 different rows connected to the same product id. I need to fetch all of these rows as one, so that I could pass the multiple values for the category at the same time. Is this possible to do via SQL query?

Comment: _“so that I could pass the multiple values for the category at the same time”_ - “pass” where? Are you talking about _input_ data for your query, or what you want to do with the result? I’m guessing you might be looking for `GROUP_CONCAT`, but it is hard to tell with the current rather unclear description.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/1427878)

Comment: actually, GROUP_CONCAT is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! :D